# (HTML/CSS) Responsive background frame vertically matching header image?

Tags: html, css, svg, html5-canvas, background-image

I've found some pretty cool website portfolio images by [Outcrowd](https://dribbble.com/shots/5005889-YanivAssociates-Home-Page) (example linked, [example 2](https://dribbble.com/shots/5115150-DevCarrot-Landing-Page)) on Dribbble.

The main idea is to have a basic (curved or shaped) background image on a landing page which also appears in a container as a top header for the main content. The problem of this construction is **responsibility**. I tried to come up with some ideas to solve this, but they didn't work out too well.

**Idea 1: image layers**

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 background-color: #e7e6ed;
}

#bg {
 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/lUphGJh.png");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom: 50%;
 background-position: bottom;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1;
}

#page {
    margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
 padding: 0;
 box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}

header {
 background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/NTwuZ1x.png");
 background-color: transparent;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover; 
 background-position: bottom;
 min-height: 300px;
}

.white {
 background-color: white;
}


/* The width of this would be different by viewports */
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="bg"></div>
    <div id="page" class="container">
  <header>
      <!-- Some content here -->
      Title
      </header>
      <section class="white">
        <!-- Main content here -->
        <br><br>Lorem ipsum<br><br>dolor sit amet.<br><br>Lorem ipsum<br>
<br>Lorem ipsum<br><br>Lorem ipsum<br><br>Lorem ipsum <br><br>
Lorem ipsum<br><br>Lorem ipsum<br><br>Lorem ipsum
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

On page load the inner line and outer line should match, but it seems impossible to make this thing responsible with image layers.

**Idea 2: SVG or HTML5 canvas**
I also tried to come up with some geometric calculations which might could work but only with javascript. (OR responsive SVG?)
The code above would look like this:

```
<div id="bg"><svg><!-- Paths and calculations --></svg></div>
```

**Idea 3: Simply impossible**

There is probably a reason why nobody does this thing...

*Please note: actual working websites Outcrowd makes don't have the frames as shown on portfolio images.*

If you have any ideas about how could this be done please answer anything could help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, though a bit of a hassle :)

First, you need a common point of reference (pivot) where both skewed images/areas have to anchor. Since the width is variable (responsiveness, and maybe take 'responsibility' for all users out there ;) ), the point has to be in the middle of the page at a certain y-position (I chose 300px).

Then we need a outer container that will be used as a kind of clipping mask (using `overflow:hidden`) and which is rotated a bit. The inner container rotates around the same point as the outer one (at x:50%, y:100% of itself) but then in the opposite direction to show the contents straight. The contents of the inner container will now be cut-off in a skewed manner. Since the rotated block leaves 'holes' in the corners, we have enlarge the outer one to be safe (`width:200%` of page) and the inner one `50%` of that (since that will cover the exact page width).

[image] [image]

Now we need to enlarge the inner container to cover the empty space left at the bottom left corner. So we adjust the `height` and change the `transform-origin`'s top coordinate accordingly to keep that point at the pivot.

[image] [image]

So now we have the background of the page. For the content we will make a second container combination inside the `.contents` div, but adjust the top positioning to account for the top margin/padding of the `.contents` block. And finally we set `overflow:hidden` and `position:relative` on the `.contents` to cut-off the overflowing content of the second container combination.

[image] [image]

So, there we go! The inner containers can now be filled with the images you need or whatever the background needs to be. For the correct positioning I use some `transform`s and `position:fixed`/`position:absolute` in combination with `left`/`top`/`bottom`, fixing the background-background and let the contents-background be able to scroll along with the rest of the page.

Have a look at the working example I made on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kcubva2f/)

**Bonus**

If you want some other shape, or just a image with a shape and transparent background, the rotation and oversizing is not needed. You just make both background containers have the same anchor/pivot (at x=50% and y=whatever you choose as bottom of bg image) and same size. This is done be scaling the `.contents` relative to the page width, so you can overscale the content's background image to match the page width.

You guessed it! There's a working example of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n2kzyLdf/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is solution is so simple and awesome!

Comment: @JaniiiFent Thanks, I added an extra example to show kind of what happens in your first mentioned example. Enjoy!

Comment: I'm very grateful for your help!